# Confused with mlflow model serve (using request)

Tags: json, kubernetes, mlflow

I'm trying to pass the .jpg image to the MLflow serve using requests.here is my code

```py
import os
import base64
import requests

import click
import pandas as pd

from mlflow.utils import cli_args

def score_model(path, host, port):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        filenames = [
            os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
        ]
    else:
        filenames = [path]

    def read_image(x):
        with open(x, "rb") as f:
            return f.read()

    data = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[base64.encodebytes(read_image(x)) for x in filenames[:1]], columns=["image"]
    ).to_json(orient="split")
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    
    response = requests.post(
        url="{host}:{port}/invocations".format(host=host, port=port),
        data={
            "image": data,
        },
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Status Code {status_code}. {text}".format(
                status_code=response.status_code, text=response.text[:500]
            )
        )
    
    return response
```

But after I run this python file, I got this message:

> Exception: Status Code 400. {"error_code": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "Failed to parse input from JSON. Ensure that input is a valid JSON formatted string. Error: 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'. Input: \nimage=%7B%22columns%22%3A%5B%22image%22%5D%2C%22index%22%3A%5B0%5D%2C%22data%22%3A%5B%5B%22%5C%2F9j%5C%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%5C%2F2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYF%5CnBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr%5C%2F2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoK%5CnCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKC

I'm trying to serve object detection model. Could you help me???
I want to get an output after I pass the image data to serve.